# AngularUI urlRouterProvider.when dynamic routing with optional parameters

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create routes with optional parameters; apparently ui.route doesn't have that capability (even though ngRoute has since almost forever). So instead I have designated them as query parameters and am trying to translate them into a proper RESTful url that will be exploded for $stateParams:

In ngRouter syntax, I would specify: `/:resource/:collection?/:type?/:index?`

In ui.router, I've specified it as: `/:resource?collection&type&index`

And I've tried to translating it dynamically with a function that returns the path (tried both with a .when() and with a .rule()):

```
$urlRouterProvider
.when('' , '/index')
.when('/', '/index')
.when( urlMatcher.source , function convertToREST( $match , $stateParams )
{
    var params = [$match.resource];
    if ( angular.isDefined($match.collection) ) params[1] = $match.collection;
    if ( angular.isDefined($match.type) )       params[2] = $match.type;
    if ( angular.isDefined($match.index) )      params[3] = $match.index;
    var result = '/' + params.join('/');
    return result;
} )
.otherwise( '/404' );
```

The above causes no view to be rendered (remove the 3rd .when() and the view renders just fine).

And manually:

```
$urlRouterProvider
.when('' , '/index')
.when('/', '/index')
.when( '/:resource?collection' , '/:resource/:collection' )
.otherwise( '/404' );
```

This apparently causes circular iteration. I got this manual idea from the ui-router's sample app: [state.js#L16](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/states.js#L16). The only difference I see is that mine starts with a parameter, but I don't see what that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, what you are trying to achieve is optional parameters for your url.

The ui.router does provide this feature, there are several options for specifying parameters. A basic parameter looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
            expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
        }
    })
Alternatively you can also use curly brackets:

// identical to previous example
url: "/contacts/{contactId}"
```

You have to resolve the params in the parent route if you are nesting states, a case like that is provided in the documentation :

```
 $stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId //*** Watch Out! DOESN'T EXIST!! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```

The solution is to use a resolve statement in the parent route

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   },
   resolve:{
      contactId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
          return $stateParams.contactId;
      }]
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams, contactId){
      contactId //*** Exists! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```

As shown fetching the result is by using *$stateParams* in your controller like this

```
$stateParams.contactId
```

You may refer the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) for more details.